# URW Grotesk for XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX (fontspec)?

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, fontspec

How can I use URW Grotesk font with XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX (fontspec) ?

Or if this is not possible/easy, are there a good heavy font replacement for it (if possible that works as well with PDFLaTeX) ?

Here is a MWE compiled with PDFLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[border=7pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
  Normal font\\
  \fontfamily{ugq}\selectfont URW Grotesk font
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't have the grotesk version, but `\setmainfont{URWBookmanL-DemiBold}` works for me, just for example

Comment: I don't understand the question, because your MWE will compile just fine with `xelatex` too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've installed `URWGrotest.ttf` in my local directory -- using `xelatex` works out of the box for this.

(Source of the font: http://font-db.com/font/URWGroteskT/57578, it's a `.zip` file, where the font file is called `font.ttf`, so I renamed it)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\setmainfont{URWGrotesk.ttf}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! Small precision, to make my MWE example works I have to download the bold version and rename it from `font.ttf` to `URWGrotesk-bold.ttf`.

Comment: @Kpym: Alright -- I just used the first one I've found ;-)